# Get admin area editor in frontend

Tags: custom-post-types, front-end, wp-editor, post-editor

I'm new to WordPress development, so apologies if this is a simple matter.

I have created several custom post types and I want to let users add/edit content from the front end. I thought it's easy. Just call `wp_editor()` with your post ID and it will know which type of controls to display (I am using Advanced Custom Fields), but it seems like `wp_editor()` displays a simple text box for each post, regardless of the post type. I know there are heaps of plug-ins that claim they can let users edit posts from the front-end, but I much prefer to have the built-in editor appear on the front end. Is there another function I can call in place of `wp_editor()` that I am missing?

Comment: This might help: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/

Comment: @Sally That's an interesting one... Another way to do what I want to achieve. So, you reckon there is no way to get WordPress to execute its editor code for me?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by that? Is the editor not displaying? Or do you want to disable one or more of its features (e.g. the Add Media button)?

Comment: @Sally I guess I was just lazy and looking for a single line function to do it for me LoL... Something like `wp_editor()`. I will implement it the way ACF says I have to

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to use a plugin, then you'd have to manually create the form (for editing the ACF fields on the front-end). [`wp_editor()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/) will just output a `textarea` with TinyMCE and Quicktags support, and not a form where you can edit custom fields...

Comment: @Sally If you post your first comment as answer I'll accept. It was easier than I thought :D

Comment: Well, I've done that! Except, I put additional stuff there. All the best! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> wp_editor() displays a simple text box for each post

It's not actually a "simple text box" =), because [`wp_editor()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_editor/) allows you to convert/turn `textarea` to a rich-text/WYSIWYG editor using the [TinyMCE library](https://www.tinymce.com/).

> I want to let users add/edit content from the front end

Because you're using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF), then there's [an easy way to do that](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/), which is basically by using [`acf_form()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/). And based on the example on [this page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/using-acf_form-to-create-a-new-post/), here's a sample Page template you can use with the Twenty Seventeen theme:

```
<?php
/**
 *  Template Name: ACF Create Post
 */

acf_form_head();

get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrap">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <header class="entry-header" style="width: 100%;">
                    <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
                    <?php twentyseventeen_edit_link( get_the_ID() ); ?>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->
                <div class="entry-content" style="width: 100%;">
                    <?php
                        the_content();

                        acf_form( array(
                            'post_id'      => 'new_post',
                            'field_groups' => array( 1858 ),
                            'submit_value' => 'Create Post',
                        ) );
                    ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </article><!-- #post-## -->
            <?php endwhile; ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- .wrap -->

<?php get_footer();
```

Hope that helps!